# How to install Debian on encrypted LVM partition?

Tags: partition, system-installation, lvm, luks, debian-installer

I don't want to use Guided-use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM because I need change encryption type and I don't need /swap

I tried to partition like this 
[image]

But it types

```
You have selected the root file system to be stored on an encrypted partition. This feature requires a separate /boot partition on which the kernel and initrd can be stored. You should go back and set up a /boot partition.
```

Is there a way to encrypt boot as well? Or there is no sense make /boot encrypted?

Also, I tried to partition them in other way and when I got to stage: Installing GRUB, I was getting errors

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can encrypt the whole disk including the boot partition since the latest grub versions allow to use crypto.

You can follow then next [guide](https://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/05/23/luks-full-disk-encryption/) or directly [ArchLinux's Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LVM_on_LUKS)